# Find the radius of a cluster, given that its center is the average of the centers of two other clusters

Tags: clustering, standard-deviation, mathematical-statistics

I do not know if it is possible to find it, but I am using Kmeans clustering, and I am stuck to the following.

In my implementation, I create with two different threads the following clusters:

CL-1{n=4 c=[1.75] r=[0.82916]}

CL-2{n=2 c=[4.5] r=[0.5]}

So, I would like to finally combine these two clusters into one final cluster. In my code, I manage to find that for the final cluster the total points are n=6, the new average of the centers is c=2.1666 but I am not able to find the final combined radius.

I know that the radius is the Population Standard Deviation, and I can calculate it if I previously know each point that belongs to the cluster.

However, in my case I do not have previous knowledge of the points, so I need the "average" of the 2 radius I mentioned before, in order to finally have this: CL-1{n=6 c=[2.1666] r=[???]}.

Any ideas? Thanks for your help.

Comment: `[(n1-1)r1^2+(n2-1)r2^2+n1(c1-2.167)^2+n2(c2-2.167)^2]/[n1+n2-1]`

Comment: It is not working, as I already know which should be the correct answer. My final result should be r = 1.49071, but now I am getting  r= 2.779.
Are you sure about your answer? Pff it seems so complicated

Comment: According to the formula (which is for r^2), the answer for r is sqrt(2.779)=1.667.